# How to speed up the query search with the issue of GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

I have the issue of using GROUP BY when select all the column from the table and in result with the poor performance in term of speed.

```
Select * from employee
group by customer_id;
```

The query above wouldn't be change,it is mandatory and fixed.It takes 17720ms is to long and the result must take shorter time, which is below 1 minute as my desired result.Since the table has many column and record, so it take much time in query searching.Is there any solution to solve this problem.Thanks.

Comment: one suggestion if you dont want all the columns then only select the column which you need. for ex:select *from employee takes more time than select emp_id,emp_name,emp_sal from employee. and you can read this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855 to understand more.

Comment: so show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement please. Another question: you've titled **speed up query search** but there is no any search :-)

Comment: sorry ,i can't show it for you because it is the confidential and protect by my company.Seek for your consideration.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For as simple as your query is, it appears almost pointless... You would not have duplicate employee IDs within an employee table, and doing a group by would still result in returning every row, every column.

However, that said, to optimize a GROUP BY, you would need an index on that column ... which I would think would already exist as the employee ID would probably be the primary key to the table.

Additionally, you don't have any aggregate columns what would warrant a group by.  Are you instead just trying to LOOK for a specific employee?  If so, that would be a different query using a WHERE clause for the criteria you are looking for.

FEEDBACK...

You updated your question and did a group by CUSTOMER ID (not employee ID).  Ok, but what do you really mean to group by..

OR... Did you want to ORDER by a customer... In other words, I want a list of all employees, but want them sorted by the customer they are associated with...  If this is the case, you would want something like...

```
select *
   from employees
   ORDER BY
      customerID, 
      employeeLastName,
      employeeFirstName
```

Without seeing your table structure(s), but if the employee table DOES have a column for the customer ID they are associated with, this query would put all employees for the same customer in a common PRE-SORT output by customer, then within that customer, sorted by the employees name (last, first).

If you have another table(s) with relationships between employees and customers, we would need to see that too to better offer an answer.

Comment: Ops, i did a stupid mistake ,instead of using employee_id ,it supposed to be customer_id.Thank for your advice.

Comment: @JCChan, see revision

Comment: sorry ,i can't show it for you because it is the confidential and protect by my company.Seek for your consideration.Thanks

Comment: @JCChan, you don't have to show actual data, nor complete table structures, just the pertinent tables / columns that show relationships.  I'm sure there are 100's if not more private table structures that are PARTIALLY offered to help a solution.  So many places have an employee table, a customer table and relationship tables.  It's common.  The actual DATA behind them is the confidential part.  We are not asking for anything like account numbers, but knowing a column is "customerName" or "company" are some basics you could disclose.

Answer (score 0):

Column with heavy type LIKE BLOB, TEXT, NVARCHAR(200 or more) will slowdown your query by a lot if you have a lot of records. I suggest to check if it is really necessary to load them all from the start.

Also, you GROUP BY seem weird. What exactly are you trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` is not just weird, it is *wrong*.  If you don't specify all the non-aggregate columns in the `GROUP BY`, you get seemingly random values for each column.  Remove the GROUP BY or explain why you think you need it.

Or maybe the "*" is not correct.  OK, you cannot show us your real column names, at least show us the real pattern to the SELECT, even if it has bogus column names.

I'm also confused as to why you call it a "search".  There is no WHERE clause, which is where "search" criteria goes.